# Run command in Puppet Master

Tags: unix, command-line, command, puppet, puppet-enterprise

Is there a way to run a command in puppet master that will bring changes to the hosts right away?

I have used different scripts using crontab to schedule my tasks and it changes whenever I have specified, but I am trying to learn if there is a way I can just hit the command in puppet master and boom! bring changes in the hosts(clients) immediately.
Let's say I want to change password in "cofig.properties" file in my 5 hosts. What would be the best way to do it from master without scheduling?

Answer (score 2):

At work we

1. push git versioned [control repos](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/cmgmt_control_repo.html) to a puppetmaster using a jenkins job,
2. then we use [r10k](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/r10k.html) to retrieve the control repo puppet module & hiera dependencies,
3. then we connect remotely using SSH to each node we want to update to run the relevant "[puppet apply](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/4.3.0/man/apply.html)" command

It works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved that problem in my infrastructure by using Puppet for Configuration Management and SaltStack for orchestration.

I have the Puppet Agent apply a SaltStack module to automatically configure each node as a minion of my Salt Master (which is also my Puppet Master), then I just SSH into my master server and tell SaltStack to run the Puppet Agent on nodes that match my criteria.

[There are several SaltStack modules on the Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=salt).

You could certainly use other tools, such as [RunDeck](http://rundeck.org/), or even Puppet's own [MCollective](https://puppetlabs.com/mcollective), but I personally found them to be more complicated to work with.

Comment: So you are saying there is no particular command you can run on Puppet master that will bring changes to the host right away?

Comment: Yes, the Puppet Master does not initiate agent runs, Agents check in with the Puppet Master on their own schedule (manually, via a cron, or as a daemon.) Puppet used to include live management, but that feature was deprecated and is probably already gone. MCollective can reach out and do this for you as I said in the answer, but it's rather complex for only this single use case. It's great, but perhaps not worth the trouble if all you want to do is this.